# WSO2 esb admin UI does not save Data base query advance propeties like fetch size

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 4.0.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.8. I have Data Services Server feature enabled(3.2.2)

I am not able to save the advance properties in the admin UI when I develop my query.

Can you please send me the sample XML dbs file which has fetch size etc mentioned?
thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a sample.

```
<data name="Test">
   <config id="test">
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">root</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">root</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.transaction_isolation">TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.initial_size">100</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.maxpoolsize">10</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.max_idle">1000</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.minpoolsize">5</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.max_wait">200</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.validation_query">select 1</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.test_on_return">true</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.time_between_eviction_runs_mills">50</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.num_test_per_eviction_run">10</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.min_evictable_idle_time_millis">8</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.remove_abandoned">true</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.remove_abandoned_timeout">4</property>
      <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.log_abandoned">true</property>
   </config>
   <query id="q1" useConfig="test">
      <sql>select * from table1</sql>
      <properties>
         <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.query_timeout">100</property>
         <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.fetch_direction">forward</property>
         <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.force_stored_proc">true</property>
         <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.force_jdbc_batch_requests">true</property>
         <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.fetch_size">10</property>
         <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.max_field_size">4000</property>
         <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.max_rows">10</property>
      </properties>
      <result element="Element" rowName="result">
         <element name="column1" column="id" xsdType="xs:string" />
      </result>
   </query>
   <operation name="op1">
      <call-query href="q1" />
   </operation>
</data>
```